# Primeng Editor, how to register quill-placeholder-module

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I´m using the [PrimeNg Editor](https://primeng.org/editor), that is an wrapper of the [Quill.js](https://quilljs.com/) editor. And I want to use this module, [quill-placeholder-module](https://github.com/jspaine/quill-placeholder-module) with it.

I´m not sure how can I add this module to the quill, that is inside the primeng component, I tried to follow the instructions on git of the module´s readme page:

First I tried to pass the module configuration to primeng component, on the modules property:

```
  modules = {
    placeholder: {
      delimiters: ['{', '}'],  // default
      placeholders: [
        { id: 'foo', label: 'Foo' },
        { id: 'required', label: 'Required', required: true }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Then on html template:

```
<p-editor #pEditor [(ngModel)]="textoPedido" [style]="{ height: '320px' }" [modules]="modules"></editor>
```

It breaks the page loading, with the error messaging:

> quill Cannot import modules/placeholder. Are you sure it was
> registered?

Then I tried to register the module as follow:

```
import getPlaceholderModule from 'quill-placeholder-module'
import Quill from 'quill';
import { Editor } from 'primeng/editor';
...
@ViewChild('pEditor') editor!: Editor;


// I saw inside editor´s code on GitHub, that it has an instance of Quill, so I tried to get this
ngAfterViewInit() {
   Quill.register('modules/placeholder', getPlaceholderModule(this.editor.quill, {
      className: 'ql-placeholder-content'
    }));
```

In this case It returns:

> ERROR TypeError: Quill.import is not a function

Maybe it´s an error on module. But, if anyone has an different approach, please let me know!